# Marker Position not being picked up - Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I am trying to find the distance between 2 markers. In the code, I place one marker on a left click and save the position of the marker to a variable "start". I then place a second marker on a left click and save the position of that marker to a variable end. I then call a function to calculate the distance between the marker but it seems that the getPosition() function isn't picking up the LatLng in the correct format. I am a bit confused on why it won't work.

Code is shown below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
var start;
var end;
var markersArray = [];
var originPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
var destinationPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:7,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(event) { 
    placeMarker(event.latLng); 
  }); 
}

function placeMarker(location) {
  if (markersArray.length == 0) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: location.toString()
            });

            // add marker in markers array
            markersArray.push(marker);
            start = marker.getPosition();
            alert(start);
        }
        else if(markersArray.length == 1)
        {
             marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: location.toString()
            });

            // add marker in markers array
            markersArray.push(marker);
            end = marker.getPosition();
            calcRoute(start, end);
        }
        else
        {

        }
}


function calcRoute(start, end) {
  originPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(start);
  destinationPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(end);

  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [originPlace],
        destinations: [destinationPlace],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, callback);

}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

     for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        outputDiv.innerHTML += origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j]
            + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in '
            + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Can you add this as a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for taking a look. The jsfiddle link is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/C4zu7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points.  Firstly, you're doing this for both start and end:

```
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            title: location.toString()
        });

        start = marker.getPosition();
```

why not just use the `location` value you already know about, instead of having to call getPosition()?

```
        start = location
```

Secondly, your values for start and end are LatLng objects, which is what the [Marker class's getPosition() function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) returns.

In your calcRoute function, you're then trying to create LatLng objects from them, which won't work:

```
originPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(start);
destinationPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(end);
```

This should just need to be:

```
originPlace = start;
destinationPlace = end;
```

**Update**: Also further on you put originPlace and destinationPlace in arrays when constructing your `request` object, which is causing the error you mention in your comment.  Here's the code I used which worked for me.

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    if (markersArray.length == 0) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            title: location.toString()
        });

        // add marker in markers array
        markersArray.push(marker);
        start = location;
    } else if (markersArray.length == 1) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            title: location.toString()
        });

        // add marker in markers array
        markersArray.push(marker);
        end = location;
        calcRoute(start, end);
    }
}


function calcRoute(start, end) {
    originPlace = start;
    destinationPlace = end;

    var request = {
        origin: originPlace,  // NOTICE THIS ONE ISN'T IN AN ARRAY...
        destination: destinationPlace,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [originPlace],  // ... BUT THIS ONE STILL IS
        destinations: [destinationPlace],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, callback);
}
```

Comment: Hi Duncan, thanks for your feedback. When I make the changes you suggested, I get the below error: 

Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string, and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number 

Any ideas on why that would be?

Comment: Perfect Duncan!! Thanks a million, I understand my mistake now!!